# Graceful way to handle item not found in a collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a foreach loop that loops through a collection, if an item is found (based on criteria as in example below), it will return that item.

If not what is the most graceful way to deal with this exception. I have a throw new notimplementedexception but I think there is a more elegant way.

Code is:

```
 foreach (SPContentType type in sPContentTypeCollection)
            {
                if (type.Name == contentTypeName)
                {
                    return type; 
                }
            }

 throw new NotImplementedException();
```

As you can see, it's not what I would call readable code. How can I make it easier for the next guy to maintain. On a side note, it does what it should from a technical perspective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well `NotImplementedException` is certainly inappropriate, because you *have* implemented the method... but what sort of exception *should* you throw? It really depends on the context, to be honest.

Sometimes it would be appropriate to return null to indicate a missing value. Other times, throwing an exception is fine - possibly an [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) for example. You should throw an exception if this situation represents an error of some description, rather than it being a perfectly reasonable situation which the caller should expect to occur.

As for the rest of the code... if you're using .NET 3.5 you could just use LINQ:

```
return sPContentTypeCollection.Cast<SPContentType>()
                              .First(type => type.Name == contentTypeName);
```

That will throw an `InvalidOperationException` for you automatically if the name isn't found. Or if you want to return null:

```
// type shortened to t to avoid scrollbars...
return sPContentTypeCollection.Cast<SPContentType>()
                              .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == contentTypeName);
```

Comment: I guess, I didn't ask the question correctly. What concerns me is the "hanging" throw directly after the work done part. It almost feels wrong to have a throw there (regardless of the exception type). If the code reached this point... something must be wrong. Is this acceptable, or would it be bad practice?

Comment: @JL: Perfectly acceptable, in my view. Nicer to use LINQ in the first place when possible, of course. If you feel it's not obvious why it's there, you can always use a comment - but I'd expect the documentation for the method itself to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm a fan of letting the caller decide what the results should really mean.  If this is a very bad thing 100% of the time, then go ahead and throw an exception.  Otherwise, let the caller decide if a null result warrants throwing or not.  How fatal is it if you can't find your type?  If it's a choice between try..catch or null handling, I'll take null handling.  However, if you need to bubble up an exception for external handling, then your hands are tied...

Comment: You can't use Linq with an SPContentTypeCollection directly.. You need to first use .Cast<SPContentType>().

Comment: @JohnFouhy: Added, thanks. I'm surprised the OP didn't mention it at the time.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on whether this is an expected or exceptional case.

If the item you compare with is passed to a method and there really *always* should be a matching item in the collection I'd throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

If it is expected that sometimes no matching item is found, I would just return `null` to indicate that the requested item was not found.

Answer (score 3):

NotImplementedException is definitively the wrong exception. I would rather throw a custom exception like for example ElementNotFoundInCollection.

Another approach would be to just return null. Then you have to check on the calling side if the returned object is not null.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Rofl that NotImplemented is wrong.  If you don't want to define your own exception class, [KeyNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception.aspx) is pretty close.

Returning `null` is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it might be worth looking at how the .NET framework itself handles this case in its own classes. For example, take `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. There are two ways to get a value out of a dictionary:

1. `myDic[key]`

   - Advantage: short; can be assigned to (and thus can use `++` and similar operators)
   - Disadvantage: throws `KeyNotFoundException` if key does not exist
2. `myDic.TryGetValue(key, out value)`

   - Advantage: does not throw (but returns `false`) if key not found
   - Disadvantage: can only get value, not set

So if you only need to *get* a value, and you don’t want to throw an exception, then the second is clearly preferable.

Therefore, in your case, write the function similarly:

```
public bool TryGetType(string contentTypeName, out SPContentType result)
{
    foreach (SPContentType type in sPContentTypeCollection)
    {
        if (type.Name == contentTypeName)
        {
            result = type;
            return true;
        }
    }
    result = default(SPContentType);
    return false;
}
```